# How to produce from the terminal in a single command 2 emacs windows?

Tags: shell, command-line, emacs, background-process

I am trying to open 2 separate windows/instances of `emacs` from the terminal in a single command. I have tried:

```
emacs &; emacs &
```

(error: `bash:syntax error near unexpected token ;` and

```
emacs & && emacs &
```

(error: `bash:syntax error near unexpected token &&` but both ways produce errors. How can I produce in a single command 2 windows of emacs to emerge?

Comment: Rather than saying the attempts "produce errors", please show the actual errors.  The messages you see may be helpful in diagnosing what is going awry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only single separator between commands: `;` or `&` or `&&` etc, so try

```
emacs & emacs &
```

If you run `emacs &; emacs &` then you start emacs in the background, and then run `;` without any command so `bash` claims it doesn't expect this separator there (`syntax error near unexpected token ;`).

Similar error you will get by just running bare `;`:

```
bash$ > ;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Not all shell behaves like that, for example in `zsh` you can even do

```
zsh$> ; ; ls; ; ls&; ls&; ; ls &; ;
```

without any problems (but not `;;` without space in-between) as it is a separator on itself, used in `case` statement).

---

The other thing you tried, `emacs & && emacs &`, is even worse as second command (after `&&`) should be run only if the first one ended successfully (this is what `&&` does). But, since we run the first command in the background shell doesn't wait for its finish, so that condition doesn't make much sense. Once again: use just single separator between commands, either `command1 & command2` or eventually `command1 && command2`.